# How to Trace through plsql procedure in postgresql 8.4

Tags: postgresql-8.4, openbravo

I am writing a **postgresql** procedure which calculates the salaries of employees on the basis of their attendance in **openbravo**.
But I am getting wrong values after calculation , Now I just wanted to trace through the procedure , The procedure gets the pinstance id 
and generates the output, But I just want to check out what is the individual values i am getting in the process, something like we use

```
system.out.println
```

in java

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call the procedure using the query

select procedure_name (arguments)

for ex:
**select calculate_salaries(arguments)**

At specific places where you want to check values just issue **RAISE NOTICE** as

**RAISE NOTICE '%' ,'value' ||value;**

you will get these values in message tab of Pgadmin and you can cross verify your results

Hope that helps

Comment: Thnx for quick reply . How to get the pinstance id bcz i am passing pinstance id to the procedure .

Comment: pinstance id is the process instance id that will be generated when you run the process through Openbravo Application dictionary.
So what you can do is 

from your procedure issue the raise exception 
 
 RAISE EXCEPTION '%' , 'pinstanceid' ||pinstanceid;
 
 Run your process in the openbravo AD you will get the error with the pinstance id.